# jQuery/AJAX: um único form que pode ser submetido para urls diferentes (POST ou PUT)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, formulário, assincronismo

tenho o seguinte cenário:

- Tenho um formulário que serve para cadastrar ou alterar um professor;
- Para cadastrar tenho um botão no topo que chama o modal para fazer o POST;
- Para alterar tenho um botão em cada linha da tabela de professores que chama o mesmo form, porém populado com os dados do professor correspondente para fazer o PUT;
- Tenho um arquivo JS com as requisições AJAX, onde eu pego o form pelo id.

O problema é o seguinte: toda vez que eu clico no botão de alguma linha para alterar o professor o form abre populado corretamente mas é submetido para o POST, isso por causa do id do form. A ação de submeter para cadastro está sempre pegando o form.

Meus AJAX são os seguintes:

```
$('#formSalvarProfessor').submit(function(event){
    alert('POST');
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: "professores",
        type: "POST",
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        dataType: "json",
        success:function(data){
            swal("Sucesso!", data.msg, "success");
        }, error: function(data){
            swal("Erro!", data.msg, "error");
        }
    });
});

$('.btn-info').click(function(){
    $('#formSalvarProfessor').submit(function(event){
        alert('PUT');
        event.preventDefault();
        var dados = $(this).data("dados");
        var id = dados.ID_PROFESSOR_PRO;
        $.ajax({
            url: "professores/"+id,
            type: "PUT",
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data){
                swal("Sucesso!", data.msg, "success");
            }, error: function(data){
                swal("Erro!", data.msg, "error");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Como posso fazer com que cada função capture o form de maneira adequada?

Answer (score 1):

Solução:

Verificar se está vindo um id do form e fazer o seguinte:

```
$('#formSalvarProfessor').submit(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var id = $("input[name=ID_PROFESSOR_PRO]").val();
    if(id){
        $.ajax({
            url: "professores/"+id,
            type: "PUT",
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data){
                swal("Sucesso!", data.msg, "success");
            }, error: function(data){
                swal("Erro!", data.msg, "error");
            }
        });
    }else{
        $.ajax({
            url: "professores",
            type: "POST",
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            dataType: "json",
            success:function(data){
                swal("Sucesso!", data.msg, "success");
            }, error: function(data){
                swal("Erro!", data.msg, "error");
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Se o ajax está dentro do click de `.btn-info` porque dentro dele tem o submit? Já removeu o sumit de dentro do click?

```
$('.btn-info').click(function(){
    alert('PUT');
    event.preventDefault();
    var dados = $(this).data("dados");
    var id = dados.ID_PROFESSOR_PRO;
    $.ajax({
        url: "professores/"+id,
        type: "PUT",
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data){
            swal("Sucesso!", data.msg, "success");
        }, error: function(data){
            swal("Erro!", data.msg, "error");
        }
    });
});
```